# Add to cart inconsistent after 2.0.2 upgrade

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax, magento-2.0.2

On my webshop the add to cart using the default Luma theme is inconsistent working / not working.

If  add to cart from frontpage, its not working, if i go to a product page and add to cart then both products will be added to cart, meaning the product i tried adding from frontpage AND the product i add from the product specific page.

I have tried looking in the console log to se if there is any ajax / js errors, but nothing is logged. Also nothing really shows anything in the error log i nginx.

I use redis for object cache, i have tried to disable redis just to rule out redis could be the issue.

I emptied all cache from Cache Management still not solved the issue.

I guess it could somehow be a session / cookie issue, but nothing really shows in the logs.

Any clues on what to look for ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever make any progress on this?

It sounds like the problems described here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3572

For me, those problems still persist and I don't have a way to solve them yet, which is frustrating. I think Magento bugs are to blame.